# where php searches the modules .so libraries on linux after compilation?

Tags: php, linux, compilation, libraries

**I was installing the PDO_INFORMIX with php 5.3.**

here is my configure flags:

```
'./configure' '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--prefix=/usr' '--exec-prefix=/usr' '--bindir=/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/etc' '--datadir=/usr/share' '--includedir=/usr/include' '--libdir=/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/var' '--sharedstatedir=/var/lib' '--mandir=/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/usr/share/info' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-config-file-path=/etc' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php.d' '--disable-debug' '--enable-shared' '--disable-rpath' '--without-pear' '--without-bz2' '--with-exec-dir=/usr/bin' '--with-freetype-dir=/usr' '--with-png-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm-dir=/usr' '--enable-gd-native-ttf' '--without-gdbm' '--with-gettext' '--with-gmp' '--with-iconv' '--with-jpeg-dir=/usr' '--with-openssl' '--with-pcre-regex=/usr' '--with-zlib' '--with-layout=GNU' '--enable-exif' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-magic-quotes' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-ucd-snmp-hack' '--enable-calendar' '--without-sqlite' '--with-libxml-dir=/usr' '--with-xml' '--enable-xml' '--with-system-tzdata' '--with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs' '--without-gd' '--disable-dom' '--disable-dba' '--without-unixODBC' '--enable-pdo' '--enable-xmlreader' '--enable-xmlwriter' '--with-mcrypt=static' '--enable-sqlite3' '--with-sqlite3' '--disable-phar' '--disable-fileinfo' '--enable-json' '--without-pspell' '--enable-wddx=shared' '--with-curl' '--disable-posix' '--disable-sysvmsg' '--disable-sysvshm' '--disable-sysvsem' '--with-pdo-informix=/opt/IBM/informix' '--enable-intl' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-mysql' '--with-mysqli' '--enable-pcntl' '--with-pdo-mysql' '--with-pspell' '--with-libedit' '--with-readline' '--enable-shmop' '--with-snmp' '--enable-soap' '--enable-sockets' '--without-pdo-pgsql' '--with-pdo-dblib' '--with-imap=/usr/local/src/imap-2007e' '--with-imap-ssl'
```

But after compilation and some tests I found out that the version of sources for PDO_INFORMIX were wrong. They were 1.3.0 . I got the right version - 1.2.6 -  and compiled pdo_informix.so separately. Than I placed the library to the *ext dir* and what I have now..

*calling the command :*

```
which -a php
```

shows that I have 2 php's. In **/usr/bin/php** and **/usr/local/bin/php**

*Calling test script* that shows the loaded version of pdo_informix with **/usr/bin/local/php** I got the right version - 1.2.6. But same test with **/usr/bin/php** shows 1.3.0 . Changing extension_dir in php.ini shows that even if he see the lib in exact directory, it is already loaded :

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'pdo_informix' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

so...

**What is the right way to find out why it is using version 1.3.0 and is there a way out without recompiling the php again?**

Answer (score 0):

As I searched and discover, after compiling with sources , php put information in its conf & cache. After recompiling with right sources of pdo_informix my problem was solved.

Hope that would help some people who would stuck with same problem =)